# I have a problem about the GoogleAppScript API deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications

I'm creating a version first. I create a project deployment from the https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx/deployments to the version I created, but it does not give the EXEC URL.

If I created a deployment manually in the project, then it gives a version-specific EXEC URL in all the versions I created with the API. How can I get EXEC URL with just API without creating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following values in the manifest file.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all the Google Apps Script deployments have an exec URL, it is created when creating a new deployment as web application.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web